# Automated selection of the correct database within a function

Tags: sql-server

I have a function that's working as I'd like it to, but I need to add one thing and I'm not able to make it happen yet.

Here's a massively simplified skeleton of the function that already works:

```
create function IC
(
@A date
)
returns table 
as
return 
(
SELECT       *

FROM        db1.dbo.table a LEFT JOIN
            db1.dbo.table2 b
            on a.randomfield=b.randomfield
            where datefield = @a
)
```

So now I can use this function to call a date-specific version of the query I wanted.  Great!  Now the issue is that I want to make this useful over time.  datefield is an archive date, and this year's data is in a different database than 2015's data, which is in a different database than 2014's, etc.  I want the function to look at @a's year, and then use that to determine which database to query against.  I've tried a variety of things that didn't work, but it seems like Dynamic SQL is the answer that everyone arrives at on the interwebs.

I want to use an if...else statement somehow, but haven't been able to put that together.  Any suggestions for how to proceed?

Comment: Did you try case when end ?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to avoid using dynamic SQL?  If so, are you fine with the need to modify the function every year (or every time a new database gets created that you need to read from)?

Comment: You will pretty much need to use dynamic sql here...but you have a problem. You are trying to do this in a function and you can't use dynamic sql in a function. Too bad you didn't partition the tables instead of making multiple copies of the database.

Comment: yeah it is either dynamic SQL in a Procedure or a lot of if thens in a function repeating pretty much the exact same code inside with a different DB name.  Either way you have a maintenance issue yearly.  with Proc route you need to maintain some sore of Year to DB Name mapping and in a function you would need to modify and add another IF statement. Partitioned Tables or Current DB + Archive DB w/ Partitioned tables would be a better structure if you can implement it

Comment: Justin, no, I'm fine with Dynamic SQL, I just don't know how to implement it correctly here.  And yes, I'm fine with a once a year update.  But from what Sean said, it doesn't sound like that could even theoretically work inside of a function.  Would using a stored procedure instead be a better choice?

Comment: I do see  now that the series of if statements does work so I can make that happen.  I am curious to see if there's a better way that involves Dynamic SQL and (I would assume) significantly shorter and more efficient code.

Answer (score 2):

Use four-part naming to select from the correct database.

Example

```
DECLARE @year INT = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())

SELECT CASE @year
   WHEN 2016 THEN   
       (SELECT 1 FROM ARCHIVE2016.dbo.SomeTable)
   WHEN 2017 THEN   
       (SELECT 1 FROM ARCHIVE2017.dbo.SomeTable)
   WHEN 2018 THEN   
       (SELECT 1 FROM ARCHIVE2018.dbo.SomeTable)
END
```

Just make sure the schema exists, even if it is with empty tables, when placing this inside a function to avoid validation errors.